# how to debug email mime type issue?

Tags: email, smtp, mime-types, mime-message, mime-mail

In short the user submits a contact us form from a web page which generates an email. The email is delivered email box that is check by Ciboodle application. Since few weeks the and additional and unwanted mime add have been appearing in the email.

Example of the received by Ciboodle

```
------=_Part_3864_25501004.1400735428511
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Message content 

(If you reply by email to the person who submitted this information from the form, please ensure that their email address is in the "To" field on your reply.)
------=_Part_3864_25501004.1400735428511--
```

Let me put more more colors to the picture.

Using the email header I was able to find out some of the hops in the message delivery. Some servers are Postfix on Linux/unix other Microsoft, the web form is Java.

This didn't help me finding where the mime type is added to the email.

What approach would you take to investigate?

Would packet capturing help at all?

Cheers in advance for your time!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add the code where you are generating the email. That will help us help you.